# Capybara : why using find('.class').click doesnt work, but using execute_script will work

Tags: capybara

I try to click button using find(.class).click just like usually, but sometimes, it doesnt work, so I have to change to execute_scirpt, it will work. I wonder why this happen, sample code will be:(this html are created when I click edit button)

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary f-light f-semibold" value="Save Changes">
```

I tried all kinds of ways, click_on "Save Changes", find().click/...
and sometimes, it will throw exception like nonodeattached.

Same situation happened to fill_in function

```
<input type="text" class="user_email input-big f-light f-semibold" value="" name="user[email]">
```

I believe there must be a lot of people meet the same problem. Any one can discuss with me?

Regards,
Lian Wu

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar problem and found it to be caused by the fact that the element was clicked too soon (the event listener had not yet been added to the button I was clicking).

For some reason, using execute script worked when clicking such an element, but just adding a sleep after finding the button also worked in my case.

I ended up having to make sure that every element on the page had finished loading before trying to click anything, and once I did that, element.click would work 100% of the time